# How do you clear an entry field in a flask webpage?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

[image]

I am working on my first flask web page.
When the user types some text and hits "enter" it is added to the file "Save_Inputs.txt".
The way it works now the user has to delete the text before entering new text.
I would like the text entry field to automatically clear when "enter" is hit.
I cannot figure out how the data is persisting and how to clear it.

----- This is the file "view_input.hmtl":

```
<form method=post action="">
  Enter text here {{ form.mytext }}
  <input type=submit value=enter>
</form
```

----- This is the main routine "flask_app.py":

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from wtforms import Form, validators, StringField
#
app = Flask(__name__)
#
class UploadText(Form):
    mytext = StringField(validators=[validators.InputRequired()])
#
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = UploadText(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        mytext = form.mytext.data
        # add text to the save file
        with open("Save_Inputs.txt", 'a') as out:
            out.write(str(mytext) + '\n')
        return render_template("view_input.html", form=form)
    else:
        return render_template("view_input.html", form=form)
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

Comment: You need Javascript. Not Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear out the entry add this line:

```
form.mytext.data = ""
```

just before the line:

```
return render_template("view_input.html", form=form)
```